# Sequential Search Issue

Tags: java

What is wrong with this sequential search? `m_t3[]` is an integer array with some combination of the numbers `0`, `1`, and  `4` filling it. (The size of the array is 9). NetBeans giving me an error message, `incomparable types: int[] and int`. The examples I've seen for this type of search look like this though.

```
int key = 0;
boolean cat = false;
for (int i = 0; i < m_t3.length; i++) {
    if (m_t3[i] == key) {
        cat = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the declaration please

Comment: NetBeans should give you the line of the error. Where is it? And how do you define `m_t3`?

Comment: i suspect `m_t3` is `int[][] m_t3`, as the error states `int[]` can't be compared to `int`. `key` is `int`, so `m_t3[i]` must be `int[]` which makes `m_t3` to `int[][]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only line that could be problematic in your code is

```
if (m_t3[i] == key)
```

It seems that your `m_t3` is as an array of arrays and not a simple array. Double-check your declaration.

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. m_t3 is a 2D array, but I had forgotten about that. I am very new to programming, so I forget small things like that a lot.